# C# MVC Model binding not working on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-phone-8

This is a heavily used working C# MVC4 Razor application. When I try it from Windows Phone 8, all the fields pass javascript validation, but are blank when the form posts to the controller. When I check the logs, I can see a few other non mobile bindings fail, but I cannot be sure if javascript was turned on for those users.

This is the Model:

```
    public class SearchFilter
    {
        public string SearchTerms { get; set; }
        public string BeginDate { get; set; }
        public string EndDate { get; set; }
        public string SearchID { get; set; }
        public List<int> SearchTypes { get; set; } 
        public bool AdvancedSearch { get; set; }
        public bool AdvancedSearchId { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string searchTypeString = "";
            if (SearchTypes != null)
            {
                searchTypeString = string.Join(" ", SearchTypes);
            }

            return "SearchTerms:" + SearchTerms + " BeginDate:" + BeginDate + " EndDate:" + EndDate +
                " SearchID:" + SearchID + " SearchTypes:" + searchTypeString +
                " AdvancedSearch:" + AdvancedSearch + " AdvancedSearchId:" + AdvancedSearchId;
        }
    }
```

This is the controller signature:

```
 public ActionResult SearchResults(SearchFilter FILTER)
     {
      try
        {
          if (FILTER.SearchTypes == null || FILTER.SearchTypes.Count < 1)
          {
           logger.Error("{0}: Auth Flag={4} Mobile={2} / Name={3} - No category selected - {1}", "SearchResults", FILTER.ToString(), Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice, Request.Browser.Browser, authorized);
                    throw new Exception("Must select at least 1 search category");
          }
        }
      catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Debug("{0}|{1} - Search Results error: {2}", "PR", "Home", ex.Message);
                ViewBag.ErrorMsg = ex.Message;
                return View("AdvancedSearchOut", oModel);
            }
```

}

This is the HTML/JS code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="~/Scripts/AdvancedSearchOut.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr.custom.12238.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript" ></script>

        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.validation.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
        $("#BeginDate").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showOn: "both",
            buttonImage: "@Url.Content("~/Content/images/calendar.gif")",
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                minDate: "-150Y",
                maxDate: "0",
                autoSize: true,
                yearRange: "1881:+0"
            });
    });
        $(function () {
            $("#BeginDate").datepicker('setDate', '-11m');
        });

        $(function () {
            $("#EndDate").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showOn: "both",
                buttonImage: "@Url.Content("~/Content/images/calendar.gif")",
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                minDate: "-150Y",
                maxDate: "0",
                autoSize: true,
                yearRange: "1881:+0"
            });
        });
        $(function () {
            $("#EndDate").datepicker('setDate', '+0');
        });

         $('#AdvSearchPage').submit(function () {

        var $fields = $("#chkBox").find('.searchckbox:checked');
          if (!$fields.length) {
            $("#cb-msg").removeClass("cb-valid"); // display checkbox error
            $("#cb-msg").addClass("cb-error");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $("#cb-msg").removeClass("cb-error"); // Don't display checkbox error
            $("#cb-msg").addClass("cb-valid");
          }

     });
 </script>
</head>

    <body>
    @model.SearchFilter
<div class="container">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchResults", "Home", FormMethod.Post,
        new { id = "AdvSearchPage", name = "AdvSearchPage", @class = "AdvSearchPage", target = "_blank" }))
    {
        <div id="searchcontainer">
            <label>Enter Keyword search term(s) or ID</label>
            <label class="error" for="SearchTerms" generated="true"></label>
            <input id="SearchTerms" class="required" maxlength="256" type="text"
                   name="SearchTerms" value="" />
            <i id="btnSearch" class="k-button fa fa-search fa-2x" title="Search" > </i>
        </div>

        <div id="dateContainer">
            <label class="error" for="EndDate" generated="true"></label>
            <div class="lbDate">Begin Date</div>
            <div class="lbDate">End Date</div>
            <br />
            <input class="startDate required dpDate" type="text" id="BeginDate" name="BeginDate" value="" />
            <input class="endDate required dpDate" type="text" id="EndDate" name="EndDate" value="" />
        </div>

        <table id="chkBox" class="container">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span id="lblSelect">(select all)</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="selectAll" id="selectAllList" />
                    <strong>&nbsp; Identify Document Type: (Check to select all types) </strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p id="cb-msg" class="cb-valid">Please select 1 or more document types</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="ccaPastAgendas" class="searchckbox" type="checkbox" value="10" name="SearchTypes">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="ccaOrdinances" class="searchckbox" type="checkbox" value="26" name="SearchTypes">

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="ccaResolutions" class="searchckbox" type="checkbox" value="30" name="SearchTypes">

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="ccaCouncilReports" class="searchckbox" type="checkbox" value="34" name="SearchTypes">

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="searchMR" class="searchckbox"
                           type="checkbox" value="105" name="SearchTypes">
                           </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="searchMM" class="searchckbox" type="checkbox" value="62" name="SearchTypes">
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="econtracts" class="searchckbox" type="checkbox" value="11" name="SearchTypes">
                     </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="finance" class="searchckbox" type="checkbox" value="104" name="SearchTypes">
                     </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="political" class="searchckbox" type="checkbox" value="102" name="SearchTypes">
                     </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="independent" class="searchckbox" type="checkbox" value="107" name="SearchTypes">

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show the code that uses this class?

Comment: Do you mean the HTML code or the C#?

Comment: Whatever is necessary to see how you are using the code and to help someone who might know the answer (unfortunately not me) help you.

Comment: Peter, I've updated the code with my HTML, JS and Logging code.

Comment: Well, given that you override almost every convention, don't use many Html helpers, and don't use data validation attributes... it's really hard to say what you might be running up against in terms of compatibility... you're breaking virtually every compatibility feature MVC gives you..